# What is the real use of SavedModelBuilder.add_meta_graph in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been playing with the saved_model API for a moment until I realise the duality between two `SavedModelBuilder` functions: `add_meta_graph` and `add_meta_graph_and_variables`

Since those APIs name seems to means that the first function saves everything and the second one only the graph. I believed wrongly that I could extract a sub graph for the second function to reduce the size of the `saved_model.pb` file.

But it happens that, even when variables keeps the same names the meta graph can loose its capacity to links the the weights data.

So far, It looks to me as if it's only useful to add tags to the same graph, which is useless since you can just add a list of them directly.

I'm lost to see any interesting properties to this `add_meta_graph` function, can someone enlighten me on this?

See the example below:

```py
import os, time

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
export_dir = dir + '/results/' + str(int(time.time()))
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

# We build our neural network and its training graph
with tf.variable_scope('placeholders'):
    x_plh = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, nb_features], name="x")
    y_plh = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 1], name="y")

with tf.variable_scope('linear_NN'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[nb_features, nb_classes], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0.05))
    y_hat = tf.matmul(x_plh, W)

with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(y_plh, y_hat))

with tf.variable_scope('predictions'):
    preds = tf.cast(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(y_hat), 1), tf.int32, name="preds")
    accuracies = tf.cast(tf.equal(preds, tf.squeeze(y_plh, 1)), tf.float32)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(accuracies, name="accuracy")

with tf.variable_scope('optimiser'):
    global_step_t = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name="global_step")
    adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-2)
    train_op = adam.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step_t)

# We train our model
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    ...

    # We add the graph and its variables to the saved_model
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.TRAINING])


# Let's clean the graph to have only needed inference nodes
serve_graph_def = tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph(
    tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), 
    ['predictions/preds']
)
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.import_graph_def(serve_graph_def, name="")
# One of another problem here, is that this function hasn't any useful check to the variable data
# just because I called the first one, I can now call this one.
builder.add_meta_graph(
    [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING]
    , signature_def_map={
        tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
            tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
                inputs={'x': x_plh}
                , outputs={'out': preds}
            )       
    }
)
builder.save(as_text=True)

# We use a temporary graph to load our saved model
# Everything is working fine here
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess: 
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.TRAINING], export_dir)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    x_plh = g.get_tensor_by_name("placeholders/x:0")
    y_plh = g.get_tensor_by_name("placeholders/y:0")
    accuracy = g.get_tensor_by_name("predictions/accuracy:0")
    acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
        x_plh: val_x,
        y_plh: val_y
    })
    print("acc: %f" % acc)

# Now I want to load the simplified graph for inference, but of course
# the link to variables is missing (no more trainable_variables and variables collections)
# So we can't use it like that
# But then, what is the purpose of this add_meta_graph function??
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], export_dir)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()

    x_plh = g.get_tensor_by_name("placeholders/x:0")
    preds = g.get_tensor_by_name("predictions/preds:0")
    p = sess.run(preds, feed_dict={ x_plh: [[.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1]] })
    print("p: %f" % p)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experiment with your code,when you use the function `extract_sub_graph`, the subgraph node names changed, no longer the same as the previously saved `graph.eg`，the node 
`'linear_NN/W'` would be changed to `'import/linear_NN/W'` in the sub graph. So the subgraph can't link the variables, because names changed.